# Transfer of CakePHP website

Tags: php, url, cakephp, dispatcher

Where I can change settings in CakePHP once transferring website from one server to another as all my links doesn't work? Links are appearing under proper domain name: example below, but once access that I have got message "Not Found"

```
http://www.thisismywebiste.com/video/1/s:date/
```

Comment: Have you used the `Html` helper to generate the links ?

Comment: Are you able to view *any* part of your site? Check your `.htaccess` file is correct; and that your `APP/webroot/index.php` contains the correct path.

Comment: I am able to view home page no pproblems

Comment: getting message "The requested URL /videos/view/151/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Problem Solved: .htaccess file missing in the rood directory

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

I think when you change your server , you transfer database because this link

```
http://www.thisismywebiste.com/video/1/s:date/
```

have s variable and date value.

Comment: yes database is transferred, I can see home page but non of the links from home page are working ?? I think so this have something to do with main path of the server ?

Comment: message I am getting "The requested URL /videos/view/151/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Problem Solved: .htaccess file missing in the rood directory

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: you check videos table that record with 151 foreign key exist or not if not exists you must create record with this id.